# How to avoid hard coding the IP of my server on my server and client file

Tags: java, python, android, websocket, server

I have a server running in a machine (lets call it `MACHINE1`). In this file, I have created the `start_server = websockets.serve(recv, "serverIP", port)`. The server is correctly running.

On the other side, I have one android application running working as a client connected to the server (note that both devices are running in the same network)

```
try {
        uri = new URI("ws://" + serverIP + ":port");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        // my code
    }
```

As I mentioned below, currently the solution is setting `serverIP` to the IP of `MACHINE1` (192.168...), and therefore, if I change the machine to another IP the connection will fail. Is there any way to create a general solution? I tried using `localhost` but I did not manage to connect to `MACHINE1`

Comment: Typically, you'd allow the user to supply that when they run the program either via command-line arguments, or using `Scanner`. You could also read it from a configuration file that you make.

Comment: so if I create one field to add the IP of the server in the android application would be a normal approach? There is nothing else more automated?

Comment: You could put the server IP in the setting for the app, and ask the user for it when the app is started for the first time.

Comment: Localhost points back to the client. Do you have a local DNS server?